# CSS Padding or Margin Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site in development that seems to have a CSS issue that I cannot find.  I installed the plugin [AJAX Event Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-event-calendar/) and dropped its shortcode `[calendar]` in the page editor.  That works as intended, but there is something pushing the calendar down somewhere in the neighborhood of 400 plus pixels.  I've checked all containing divs, and the calendar divs as well.  I also see no errors in the console.  I just can't seem to locate what's pushing it down.

The page in question can be seen [here](http://dev01.andywarren1.com/visualfaithministry/events/calendar/).

Comment: Post code, not links. See [FAQ] for why.

Comment: First, there wasn't any specific code to post.  I know quite well how to use this site.  Second, this question has been answered and the answer has been accepted, no need to place your random non-constructive comments on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your custom.css file fix this:

```
    #aec-container {
position: relative;
float: none;
    }
```

with this:

```
#aec-container {
position: relative;
float: left;
    }
```

i tried and it works.

Comment: Seems super simple, and I did try it.  Only issue is that it seems to shrink the calendar way down and disproportion its date boxes.  Did it do this when you tried?

Comment: i dont know how it should look like but here is a screenshot of i how see it after the fix http://i.imgur.com/rWeiR2F.jpg

Comment: Yep, I just added `#aec-calendar {width: 700px;}` to my stylesheet.  For some reason it was missing a width.  Fixed now, your screenshot is how it should look.  It was all squashed in on itself prior to adding that width.  Thanks for the speedy answer.  Accepted.